# latex-mode keywords string highlight based on patterns

Tags: latex, syntax-highlighting

In LaTeX I use a number of custom commands for which I created a keyword highlight in `init.el`. For example, I have a command to write argmax/argmin and therefore I have the following in in my `init.el`

```lisp
;; latex ::  custom keywords highlight
(setq font-latex-match-reference-keywords
      '(("argmax" "[{")
        ("argmin" "[{")
    ))
```

I also use custom commands that use a prefix or a suffix word, e.g. `\figref`, `\tabref`, `\algoref`, etc. Is there any simple way to construct a keyword highlight so that any command that finish with `ref` is highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like that variable does not support regexp patterns, only the list of keywords. I guess you have to list them all if you use that variable. Otherwise you have to do your own font-lock mechanism.

Comment: "\<[a-zA-Z]+ref\>" does not seem to work.